# How are controller actions invoked Asp .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have been wondering how controller actions are invoked in Asp .Net Core after a request has been matched to an action based on the configured routes.

Are they invoked by reflection? If they are invoked this way there would be quite a performance impact.

Or are the routes and corresponding controllers dynamically compiled in some way so that the actions from the controllers are invoked directly.

Comment: Why do you assume that calling a pregenerated reflection method call instance has a serious performance overhead compared to all the other overhead asp.net has ANYWAY?

Comment: There is nothing to worry there. In such cases all reflection calls are done once and the results then are cached. ASP.NET Core currently ranks #10 in the [TechEmpower Web Framework plain text benchmark](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r18&hw=ph&test=plaintext), just a fraction behind the top 9 which mostly offer a much narrower feature set.

Comment: It may be a daunting task, but if you're curious about the inner workings of the framework you can always have a look: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore

Comment: More specifically, look at the [ControllerActionInvoker](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b23ea5b6683b08e8d168ccf49e0fc8515077ee2e/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ControllerActionInvoker.cs) and [ControllerActionInvokerCacheEntry](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ControllerActionInvokerCacheEntry.cs) classes in the `dotnet/aspnetcore` repo.

Comment: Why not add that comment as an answer. It answers my question perfectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since ASP.NET Core is open sourced, you can browse the source code at [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore).

More specifically, look at the [ControllerActionInvoker](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b23ea5b6683b08e8d168ccf49e0fc8515077ee2e/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ControllerActionInvoker.cs) and [ControllerActionInvokerCacheEntry](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ControllerActionInvokerCacheEntry.cs) classes in the `dotnet/aspnetcore` repo.